# How do you specify array literals, in this case containing integers, in Objective-C?

Tags: objective-c

I presently have:

```
transformations = @[@[1, 1], @[1, -1], @[-1, 1], @[-1, -1]];
```

What type should give this? (NSArray *)?

Comment: as it stands that's a compile-time error, since `NSArray`s cannot contain primitive values. Check the answers below

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's an `NSArray` of `NSArrays`. Although you should transform the scalars into `NSNumbers`. :)

```
transformations = @[@[@1, @1], @[@1, @-1], @[@-1, @1], @[@-1, @-1]];
```

From the [Clang Documentation](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/ObjectiveCLiterals.html):

> // integral literals.
>    NSNumber *fortyTwo = @42;             //
>   equivalent to [NSNumber numberWithInt:42]
>   NSNumber *fortyTwoUnsigned
>   = @42U;    // equivalent to [NSNumber numberWithUnsignedInt:42U]
>    NSNumber *fortyTwoLong = @42L;        // equivalent to [NSNumber
>   numberWithLong:42L]
>   NSNumber *fortyTwoLongLong = @42LL;   //
>   equivalent to [NSNumber numberWithLongLong:42LL]

Answer (score 1):

Arrays must have an object, not a primitive type, so you will need to populate your array with `NSNumber`s. For example, use `@(1)`, and get the values using `transformations[x][y].intValue`.

Answer (score 1):

```
NSArray *transformations = @[@[@1, @1], @[@1, @(-1)], @[@(-1), @1], @[@(-1), @(-1)]];
```

Comment: Some day (maybe April 1) we're going to have to have a (unauthorized) "Meaningful Objective-C statement with the most "@" characters" contest.

Comment: may be. I too didn't like writing all those '@'

Answer (score 1):

You can wrap the int literals into an NSNumber object.

```
NSNumber *intNumber = [NSNumber numberWithInt:-1];
```

etc.

You can also use the quick syntax for an NSNumber by writing:

```
@(-1)
```

within your NSArray statement.